# Why is my background-image not showing up on my page?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to make that image appear in my logo square, why?
background-color works perfectly well, but in this one the image won't appear and when I inspect with Chrome it gives that yellow warning + it bars it.

Can anyone help me figure it out?

I tried adding it in the HTML code already, if that helps..

```
.logo {

    margin:auto;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background-image: url=('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9c/Osaka_-_Night_View.jpg');
}
#logotext {
    color:red;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:62px;
}
#navbar {
    background-color:black;
    height:50px;
    width:800px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:38px;
}
#navbartext {
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:370px;

}
#content {
    background-color:black;
    height:650px;
    width: 800px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:38px;
}
#contenttext {
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:370px;
    margin-top:300px;

}
#footer {
    background-color:black;
    margin:auto;
    height:75px;
    width:800px;
    margin-top:38px;
}
#footertext {
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:370px;
    margin-top:25px;
}
```

Comment: remove "=" in logo class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a syntax error, remove `=` from your code.

**Wrong:**

```
background-image: url=('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9c/Osaka_-_Night_View.jpg');
```

**Correct:**

```
background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9c/Osaka_-_Night_View.jpg');
```

Comment: Goddammit.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/W2Tq6/1/)

remove `=` in your `url=('')`

it should be..

```
background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9c/Osaka_-_Night_View.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

change this class..

```
.logo {

margin:auto;
width:150px;
height:150px;
background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9c/Osaka_-_Night_View.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check CSS:

```
background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9c/Osaka_-_Night_View.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way to use the background-image property in css.

```
background-image:url('paper.gif');
```

So in your case it will be:

```
background-image:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9c/Osaka_-_Night_View.jpg');
```